# apex class code to access the case records on button click from the vf page

Tags: apex, visualforce, rest-api

**apex:**

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/FieldAccount/*')
global class restapiget {
    @HttpGet
    global static Case getAccount() {
      RestRequest request = RestContext.request;
      String caseids= request.requestURI.substring(request.requestURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);

      Case result =  [SELECT Id,Subject FROM Case WHERE Id = :caseids];              

      return result;

    }
}
```

The above code is working fine while i test it from workbench. Now i have got the access token. The issue is from vf page button on button click i need to access the record using access token . kindly help.

Comment: are you using same class as REST API some other purpose? if not then don't define that class a REST API and bind it to VF page using controller

Comment: @rohit .....thnx for the response. actually i am new to rest api. Actually on button click i am able to get the access token(response.getBody()) on vf page, now using  that access token on button click i need to access the casr records.

Comment: why you need access token? VF can directly access case records by calling method of a controller. You don't need to write REST API for that.

Comment: @rohit...thatz all right. I understood your point. but i am just trying to understand if the external application like java tries to access our force.com resources,they have to be uploaded in connected apps. And access token is generated for that. So, using that access token i have to access the case records and i need http class code where in  request.setheader() i can set the access token as the parameter.